# Need Intel Core 2 Duo E7500 drivers

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, display-driver

I can't find the drivers of my processor which is Intel Core 2 Duo E7500. I have searched almost the whole internet I can't find the appropriate drivers for my processor. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

#### I can't find the drivers of my processor

See the following from Intel regarding drivers for their chipsets.

---

#### Find Intel® Processor Software and Drivers

> Software support for your processor would be included in your
>   motherboard's BIOS.
>
> Contact your motherboard vendor for your boards latest BIOS.
>
> All BIOS update files for Intel® Desktop Boards are available on
>   [Intel's Download Center](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx).
>
> **Video drivers**
>
> Intel introduced processor graphics in 2009. [The Intel® Driver Update
>   Utility for Graphics](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics) will help you identify and install the
>   graphics driver if applicable to your system. For more information
>   about Intel® Processors with built-in graphics capability, visit the
>   [Frequently asked questions on Intel® HD Graphics](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-031174.htm) page.
>
> [Intel® Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/support/detect.htm) - Automatically identify and find
>   drivers The Intel® Driver Update Utility keeps your system up-to-date.
>   It detects which driver updates are relevant to your computer, and
>   then helps you install them quickly and easily.
>
> **BIOS updates – why can’t I find them?**
>
> Any BIOS updates released specifically for your processor would be
>   included in BIOS updates for your motherboard. For compatibility
>   issues, check to see if your motherboard supports your processor and
>   if a specific revision of BIOS is needed for processor support. Please
>   refer to your system or motherboard manufacturer's website to find
>   updates for your specific board.
>
> **Audio drivers**
>
> These type of drivers are specific to your motherboard, and not your
>   processor. So to find the correct drivers for your system, you will
>   need to see your system or motherboard manufacturer's website.
>
> **Chipset software**
>
> Software designed for your motherboard’s chipset would be found on the
>   [Intel chipset support site](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/#software). It is not available for download from
>   the Intel® Processor support site. Chipset.inf needs to be run only
>   once after installing your operating system and before installing your
>   drivers. You do not need to update this file, it is not a driver.
>
> **Processor utilities**
>
> Identify your Intel® Processor - [Intel® Processor Identification](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-015477.htm)
>   utilities Discover system components inside your PC - [System
>   Information Utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/idyp) Test your processor functionality - [Intel®
>   Processor Diagnostic Tool](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-031726.htm)

Source [Find Intel® Processor Software and Drivers](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-025633.htm)

Comment: i posted this question from different id but now i m unable to recover it (sorry for that). i have tried it. All of it. The driver update utility doesn't find any driver on my machine

Comment: Have you tried to [merge accounts](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)? Anyway, your CPU doesn't have built-in GPU so you need no drivers for it. But, as @DavidPostill noted, *motherboards have drivers*. Find your motherboard model, visit manufacturer's website and download drivers for your model.